# Image upload with Firebase React Native

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I want to upload an image to Firebase Storage from a React Native app, the Firebase web sdk only works on iOS so I am giving Firebase React Native a go. The docs are empty but someone pointed my to the [old docs](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/docs_old/docs/modules/storage.md) so my code looks like this.

```
firebase.storage().ref('/rn-firebase2.jpg').putFile(imgFile.uri)
    .on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        //Current upload state
        console.log('state_changed: ', snapshot);
    }, err => {
        //Error unsubscribe();
        console.log('err: ', err);
    }, uploadedFile => {
        //Success unsubscribe();
        console.log('uploadedFile: ', uploadedFile);
    });
```

When ran, I get

> "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):". A file is uploaded to
>   the Cloud Storage but it unusable.

Anyone has successfully gotten this to work on iOS and Android? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: checkout this https://github.com/CodeLinkIO/Firebase-Image-Upload-React-Native